# Get Proper Progress Updates on Two Long Waited Concurrent Processes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I implemented background video processing using .net ffmpeg wrapper http://www.mediasoftpro.com with progress bar indication to calculate how much video is processed and send information to web page to update progress bar indicator. Its working fine if only single process works at a time, but in case of two concurrent processes (start two video publishing at once let say from two different computers), progress bar suddenly mixed progress status. 
Here is my code where i used static objects to properly send information of single instance to progress bar.

```
static string FileName = "grey_03";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Params["file"] != null)
        {
            FileName = Request.Params["file"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
public static double ProgressValue = 0;
public static MediaHandler _mhandler = new MediaHandler();

[WebMethod]
public static string EncodeVideo()
{
    // MediaHandler _mhandler = new MediaHandler();
    string RootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
    _mhandler.FFMPEGPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\ffmpeg_july_2012\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
    _mhandler.InputPath = RootPath + "\\contents\\original";
    _mhandler.OutputPath = RootPath + "\\contents\\mp4";
    _mhandler.BackgroundProcessing = true;
    _mhandler.FileName = "Grey.avi";
    _mhandler.OutputFileName =FileName;
    string presetpath = RootPath + "\\ffmpeg_july_2012\\presets\\libx264-ipod640.ffpreset";
    _mhandler.Parameters = " -b:a 192k -b:v 500k -fpre \"" + presetpath + "\"";
    _mhandler.OutputExtension = ".mp4";
    _mhandler.VCodec = "libx264";
    _mhandler.ACodec = "libvo_aacenc";
    _mhandler.Channel = 2;
    _mhandler.ProcessMedia();
    return _mhandler.vinfo.ErrorCode.ToString();
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetProgressStatus()
{
    return Math.Round(_mhandler.vinfo.ProcessingCompleted, 2).ToString();
    // if vinfo.processingcomplete==100, then you can get complete information from vinfo object and store it in database and perform other processing.
}
```

Here is jquery functions responsible for updating progress bar indication after every second etc.

```
$(function () {
         $("#vprocess").on({
             click: function (e) {
                 ProcessEncoding();
                 var IntervalID = setInterval(function () {
                     GetProgressValue(IntervalID);
                 }, 1000);
                 return false;
             }
         }, '#btn_process');

     });
     function GetProgressValue(intervalid) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "concurrent_03.aspx/GetProgressStatus",
             data: "{}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 // Do something interesting here.
                 $("#pstats").text(msg.d);
                 $("#pbar_int_01").attr('style', 'width: ' + msg.d + '%;');
                 if (msg.d == "100") {
                     $('#pbar01').removeClass("progress-danger");
                     $('#pbar01').addClass("progress-success");
                     if (intervalid != 0) {
                         clearInterval(intervalid);
                     }
                     FetchInfo();
                 }
             }
         });
     }
```

The problem arises due to static mediahandler object

```
public static MediaHandler _mhandler = new MediaHandler();
```

I need a way to keep two concurrent processes information separate from each other in order to update progress bar with value exactly belong to that process.

Comment: Have you considered off-loading this work to a dedicated service instead of running in the ASP.NET context?

Comment: @BryanCrosby all processing perform in background, mediahandler pro sent process completed status via _mhandler.vinfo.ProcessingCompleted which works well on all processes. but problem is when i sent this information to progress bar via ajax call, mixed progress completion information sent sometime from one process, some time from another. i need to defferentiate two process information in some way.

Comment: You are still hosting the `MediaHandler` under an ASP.NET context.  Consider offloading it to a service so you can periodically ask the service whether it is finished or not.  Create some type of unique identifier when the service starts so that you may query it to see if it's finished or not.

Comment: @BryanCrosby process finish indication is not an issue, sending process completion information in real time to main asp.net page via jquery ajax in order to show progress status to user. it can't be achieve if i offload process from asp.net context.

Comment: Yes it can.  You can expose a WCF service and query the progress over HTTP via AJAX.

Comment: thanks @BryanCrosby i will try WCF and let u know.

Comment: i will face issue in WCF architure too, problem is how to distinguish if two separate progress bar sent request on same time to page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misunderstanding here.

Because you are using a `static` variable, you are seeing concurrency problems.  This is because in ASP.NET, `static` variables are shared by all requests because they are once-per-AppDomain until the app pool recycles.

You should expose a WCF end-point that you can use to ask your service whether it is finished or not.  This service should work a queue and call your `ffmpeg` program for each item in the queue.  You haven't mentioned how many users will be calling your page, but it's probably better to design it this way so you can more simply control how many items the server is allowed to process at once.  You will also run in to less problems because you are running a process under a service context rather than under ASP.NET.

Comment: Isn't a static an instance-per-appdomain that loads the class, rather than across app pools?

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni: Whoops, that's what I meant to write.  Unless they are marked [ThreadStatic] then they are once per appdomain.

Comment: @BryanCrosby thanks for wonderful concept, +1 vote for this. i will give time to deeply analyze and implement it in my solution later.however my concurrency issue resolved by using static list of concurrent objects instead of single static instance which was shared across multiple users.